# Creating an object on the heap without new

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, heap-memory

In C++, is it possible to create an object on the heap without using `new` or `malloc` ?

I think if I use an STL container like a `vector` it will be put on the heap. If I do:

```
vector<Object> listObjs = vector<Object>();

Object x = Object(...);
...
listObjs.push_back(x);
```

Where do the Objects created here reside?

Comment: `malloc()` should not be used in `C++`.

Comment: You can use malloc in C++; you just need to be careful not to expect it to call constructors.

Comment: `vector` puts its objects somewhere.  Unless you're writing an allocator object or something fancy like that, you don't need to worry about whether their memory is on the heap, the stack, or in the computer's dustbunnies.

Comment: Though if you have your quantum cpu writing on dust bunnies you may also wish to consider the shielding from solar radiation and the beast of traal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object denoted by `x` resides on the stack. `vector::push_back` will copy it to the heap.

The [allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allocator_%28C%2B%2B%29) object inside the `vector` will probably be implemented using `new` or `malloc`, although it is possible that it uses another, low-level API. For instance, both Unix and Windows offer memory mapping APIs, which in turn may be used to implement `malloc`, `new` and allocators.

Comment: Does that mean I throw the created objects away after `push_back()`?

Comment: @pessimo: Yes. Vector makes a copy.

Comment: Also, I think `vector` is allowed to use a "small container optimization", in which case `push_back` would copy elements to a location on the stack (inside the `listObjs` object) until that's full, then the vector would resize.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yep; it can allocate wherever it likes. But if the elements are on the freestore (not "heap" please, guys), then at some point something, somewhere, is doing a `malloc` syscall.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I haven't read the `vector` spec in the standard. I suppose it wouldn't disallow your optimization, but wouldn't that waste a lot of stack space for any `vector` of more than trivial size?

Comment: @Tomalak: `malloc` is not a syscall, at least not on any platform I've seen.

Comment: @Tomalak: if you're going to assert the existence of anything so implementation-specific as a "syscall", surely you might as well just admit that the free store is located on the OS's heap? ;-)

Comment: @larsmans: probably it would, but for all we know in this example `sizeof(Object)==1`, in which case an optimization up to size, say, 8 or 12 (twice as much on 64 bit platforms) is probably plausible without ever wasting any memory. I admit that the case for the optimization is less compelling than it is with `std::string`, I only raised it because I'm not sure whether the question is (for some odd reason) asking how to *guarantee* creating an object as specified.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` is doing `new` there.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is doing `std::allocator::allocate`. I'm not sure if that function is required to get memory from `new`.

Comment: @larsmans: It's not. I'm simplifying a bit; shoot me. ;) But if the elements are on the freestore then something, somewhere, at some level, is doing a `malloc` syscall and by default in most stdlib implementations that's through `new`.

Comment: @larsmans: if `std::allocator<Object>` is specialized by the user then it could do anything, otherwise the unspecialized template uses global operator new (20.4.1.1/6).

Answer (score 0):

Coming from C#/java ?

`std::vector<Object> listObjs;` create a container on the stack that manage an array of Object allocate on the heap

`listObjs.push_back(Object());` allocate an array of size + 1, copy the old array to the new one and assign Object() to the last one